# Material-UI - How to change default color for dark theme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, themes, material-ui

In Material-UI when changing the theme to dark, some components turn its color to `#424242` and some other to `#212121`.

It seems those colors come from `theme.palette.grey`:

```
theme.palette.grey[800]: '#424242'
theme.palette.grey[900]: '#212121'
```

What if I want to use the color of `#121212` instead of `#212121`?

I did this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    grey: {
      900: '#121212'
    },
  },
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MyComponent/>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

And it works, components that used `#212121` now it using `#121212` as its color.

But it's not the case for `#424242` color, somehow I couldn't override it using the same trick.

How can I change the use of color `#424242` with other color (e.g `#000000`) in dark mode.

**EDIT:**

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xe1sp)

from official docs code in index.js I just add this:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const themeX = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
    grey: {
      800: "#000000", // overrides failed
      900: "#121212" // overrides success
    }
  }
});
```

And wrap `Demo` with `MuiThemeProvider`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={themeX}>
    <Demo />
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

Comment: Please indicate where this color is occurring and show the code involved in rendering that portion of the page. Also helpful to include a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) demonstrating the color you want to change.

Comment: I just added CodeSandbox example

Comment: You still haven't indicated which element you are trying to affect the color of.

Comment: The SwipeableViews backgroundColor which use #424242 color

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `demo.js` is the following code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    width: 500,
  },
}));
```

This is controlling the background color for the `div` that wraps the entire content. In order to control this, you need to either specify a different color directly in the `makeStyles` call or you need to customize `theme.palette.background.paper`. For instance:

```
const themeX = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
    grey: {
      800: "#000000", // overrides failed
      900: "#121212" // overrides success
    },
    background: {
      paper: "#000000"
    }
  }
});
```